# compiling sendmmsg get undefined reference to `sendmmsg'?

Tags: c

I tried to compile the following code witch send multiple massages using sendmmsg() in c, but it gives me a compiler error " undefined reference to `sendmmsg' ". I tried to google it, but not found any result!

I got the code from this page: http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/sendmmsg.2.html

and I need more resources about recvmmsg() to read.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include < netinet/ip.h>
#include < stdio.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < string.h>
#include < sys/types.h>
#include < sys/socket.h>

int
main(void)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  struct mmsghdr msg[2];
  struct iovec msg1[2], msg2;
  int retval;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd == .1) {
    perror("socket()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  sa.sin_port = htons(1234);
  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == .1) {
    perror("connect()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(msg1, 0, sizeof(msg1));
  msg1[0].iov_base = "one";
  msg1[0].iov_len = 3;
  msg1[1].iov_base = "two";
  msg1[1].iov_len = 3;

  memset(&msg2, 0, sizeof(msg2));
  msg2.iov_base = "three";
  msg2.iov_len = 5;

  memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  msg[0].msg_hdr.msg_iov = msg1;
  msg[0].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 2;

  msg[1].msg_hdr.msg_iov = &msg2;
  msg[1].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;

  retval = sendmmsg(sockfd, msg, 2, 0);
  if (retval == .1)
    perror("sendmmsg()");
  else
    printf("%d messages sent\n", retval);

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: is there <sys/socket.h> included???

Comment: Yes,
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/socket.h>

Comment: In the link you reference, in the example, tells you what include files must be met, also, it says that it is Linux specific.

Comment: Yes I know, I got the code copy and past to Linux machine and compiled it using gcc -O2 -o sender sender.c
but gcc get compiler error undefined reference to sendmmsg

Comment: It would help if you posted your actual code and actual compiler error message.  The sample you're working from is simple, so this shouldn't be difficult.  Your problem is still a bit vague - it could even be a link error.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code
compile it: gcc -O2 -o test test.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message you're getting, sendmmsg() isn't defined at link time. According to the man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html), support for sendmmsg() was added in glibc version 2.14. What version of glibc are you using?

If sendmmsg() is supported by your kernel, but isn't provided by existing system libraries, your best alternative might be to "roll your own" sendmmsg() using syscall(2).

Comment: +1 That must be the reason, OP, you can check your glibc version using `ldd --version` from console

Comment: Edited to clarify and suggest possibility of using syscall(2).